# How to step into with the rails pry debugger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, pry

The [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) is very usefull. It has the following commands :

```
Pry.commands.alias_command 'c', 'continue'
Pry.commands.alias_command 's', 'step'
Pry.commands.alias_command 'n', 'next'
Pry.commands.alias_command 'f', 'finish'
```

However, I dont know how to **step into**. That is, when a function is called, I want the debugger to open up this function and show me its execution.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Doesn't the command *step* provide just what you want? Salute.

Answer (score 17):

As you said @deivid, `step` steps into, while `next` steps next. I was mistaken.

Comment: Yeah, in every ruby debugger I know, **step** means _step into_, **next** means _step over_, **finish** means _step out_ and **continue** means... _"step away"_

Comment: Few comments and answers and non has been tested. Try the **next** and you will see it steps **into** the function, **not** over!

Comment: for what it's worth: I used pry-debugger for a long time and next worked, but I agree with @Aleks that now it steps into. I have no idea why.

Comment: `next` steps over now.